# RAM use with Gstreamer filesink increases indefinitely

Tags: c, gstreamer, ram, gstreamer-1.0, nvidia-deepstream

I've been getting OOM errors after running my Gstreamer pipeline for long periods of time.
Running on a Jetson-Xavier Devkit.

The smallest reproducible example:
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! omxh265enc ! qtmux ! filesink location=test.mp4 -e`

Memory before running:

```
sh-5.1# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 3  0      0 5384300 307304 18665008    0    0     9    59   28   51  6  2 92  0  0
```

Memory after running 2 min:

```
sh-5.1# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
10  0      0 5151928 307560 18820992    0    0     9    59   29    1  6  2 92  0  0
```

Memory after running 10 min:

```
sh-5.1# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 4  0      0 4794396 308008 19138836    0    0     9    60   31    5  6  2 92  0  0
```

Memory after stopping:

```
sh-5.1# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 4836532 308040 19140984    0    0     9    60   31    5  6  2 92  0  0
```

RAM utilization never stops increasing relatively linearly, and the cache doesn't get freed when I stop the process.

This doesn't happen if I replace the `filesink` with a `fakesink`:
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! omxh265enc ! qtmux ! fakesink`

Memory before running:

```
sh-5.1# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 4836532 308040 19140984    0    0     9    60   31    5  6  2 92  0  0
```

Memory after running 2 min:

```
sh-5.1# vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 4608692 308192 19141064    0    0     9    60   32    7  6  2 92  0  0
```

I have noticed the same issue with a `splitmuxsink`, when using `mp4mux`, and when switching out the `omxh265enc`, so I'm assuming there's something going on with the `filesink`?

Does anyone have any insight into this or know how to prevent gstreamer from using all my memory?

Comment: sounds like a fun debugging project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using nvv4l2h265enc instead?

Edit:
I just used nvv4l2h265enc with filesink, and I'm seeing the same issue as you, very intersting.

Edit2: I think it's a matter on how commands like `free` or `vmstat` calculate virtual memory usage. For example the `free` command indeed shows less and less free memory overtime, however if you look at the `used` column, it does not increase overtime. Also using graphical monitor tools on the system like gnome system monitor, show that the memory does not increase in time.

Comment: Yes, I normally use nvv4l2h265enc and see this issue but wanted a minimal example without it because in the past there have been memory issues with it.
I do see that the cache is increasing at a similar rate free is decreasing, but that doesn’t explain the OOMs. Could the application need more buffers/cache than is available on the system?